# Mongodb. Convert field to bool

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to change field type to bool among all documents in collection. Here is the code

```
db.product.find().forEach(function(doc) {
if (doc.checked === "Y") {
doc.checked = true;
} else if (doc.checked === "N") {
doc.checked = false;
}
db.product.save(doc);
});
```

Mongodb returns no error but doesn't convert fields.

Comment: Can you paste the console output of db.product.findOne()?

Comment: {
    "_id" : ObjectId("56671a312253ec2b40921d2d"),
    "date" : ISODate("2015-12-08T17:58:09.000Z"),
    "checked" : "Y",
    "ports" : "38577,8081,6706"
    }

Comment: Your script logic is fine, i tested and it works. Are you running the script on the correct database? Is the collection sharded?

Comment: Yes..  Your logic is correct and it worked fine for me..

Comment: you can use bulk update as well. You can try the below query.  `var bulk = db.product.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
 bulk.find({checked:'Y'}).update({$set:{checked:true}});
 bulk.find({checked:'N'}).update({$set:{checked:false}});
 bulk.execute();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved problem using 'db.product.update' instead of 'db.product.save'